# Menu Pills on Joomla 3.4

Tags: templates

I am creating a new website (GoDaddy/Joomla 3.4).  Menu pills are working (Home button is displayed and working).

What do I need to do to add additional menu pills (e.x. 'About Us', 'Contact Us')?

[I don't think this is critical data - I am using the 'protostar' template.]

Comment: One possible solution:  with web-page visible, rt click on button and chose 'inspect element'. Go into host website, hunt around until I find matching filename, edit that file (adding 'pills'), saving file then reloading web-page.  Slow, tedious - and not very user friendly.

Comment: Found an site answering the question "How to edit a Joomla 3 template":  http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/edit-template.    It helped locate the area in Joomla where template editing can occur.  So far, have not found where it specifies the 'Home' button or the link that goes with it.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around on the internet and finding nothing of any real help, decided to experiment on site - discovered solution by accident.

1) Create a new article (the content that will be tied to the new menu button).  For me, this was going to an existing article, saving it as a copy and editing the copy - then changing the Title to what I wanted.
2) Similar to step 1, I went to menus, opened an existing menu item, saved as copy.  Then I changed the Title, changed the article it was linked to, saved.

When I swapped tabs back to the wep-page and reloaded it (ctrl+f5), new menu button appeared...along with the link to take it to the new page.  DONE